# unable to run ionic serve after upgrading to ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

so i have an old ionic v1 project that was done. i have since moved on to ionic v2 and now i wanted to go back to the old v1 project to change some stuff but i'm unable to run ionic serve. when i run 'ionic serve' in the v1 project root.. i get the following...

```
Looks like a fresh checkout! No ./node_modules directory found. Would you like to install project dependencies? (Y/n)
```

it looks like its looking for the node_modules folder, but i never remember having the node_modules folder in my v1 project. there's also a file called package-lock.json file in the root that i'm not familiar with. will downgrading the ionic cli fix this? my current ionic info is...

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v6.11.2
npm  : 5.3.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading an old project to Ionic2, you'll discover the project folder's organization to be a bit different, including some new files.

What happened when you responded Y to install project dependencies? Maybe there are some npm modules that your project needs?

Comment: when i responded 'yes', it ran 'npm install' and got a FILE_NOT_FOUND error

Comment: Oh, that's not good. I suspect this is your root problem. Unfortunately, I don't have full visibility to your project. Take a close look at the FILE_NOT_FOUND error and determine which files specifically can't be located. If you can do that, you might be able to pinpoint which NPM module(s) are having difficulty with installing.You may need to go to the Ionic forums for additional support on this.